# Nativescript iOS error

Tags: nativescript

I am using NS 2.3 with AppBuilder.  Recently I started seeing the following error in my console:

**UIDataDetectorTypeLegacyPhoneNumber is incompatible with other types**

Here is the markup of th epage where the error occurs:

```html
<Page xmlns="http://schema.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" actionBarHidden="true" loaded="pageLoaded" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" xmlns:sharedDrawers="widgets/drawers">

  <drawer:RadSideDrawer id="mainDrawer">

    <drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
      <ScrollView id="wrapper" opacity="0">
        <DockLayout stretchLastChild="true">
          <StackLayout class="bg" dock="top" paddingTop="7">
            <GridLayout id="mainHeader" rows="auto" columns="auto, *, auto" dock="top">
              <Button class="icomoon-icon" text="&#xe90a;" row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" tap="openDrawer" fontSize="18"/>
       <Label class="title" horizontalAlignment="center" text="Page Title" row="0" col="1" />
              <Button class="icomoon-icon" text="&#xe910;" row="0" col="2" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" tap="close" fontSize="20" />
            </GridLayout>
            
            <Image src="~/images/img.png" width="130" />
            
            <Label text="{{ greeting }}" class="greeting" />
          </StackLayout>

          <StackLayout dock="top" cssClass="content">
            <Label class="heading" text="some text..." textWrap="true" />
            
            <Label id="text" text="some more text..." class="text" textWrap="true" />
            
            <HtmlView id="h-privacy" class="h-view" html="{{ privacy }}"  tap="toPrivacyPolicy" />

            <Label cssClass="button" text="continue" tap="next" />

            <HtmlView id="h-notices" class="h-view" html="{{ notices }}"  tap="toNotices" marginTop="10" />
            
          </StackLayout>
        </DockLayout>

      </ScrollView>
    </drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>

    <drawer:SideDrawer.drawerContent>
      <sharedDrawers:mainDrawer />
    </drawer:SideDrawer.drawerContent>
  </drawer:RadSideDrawer>
  
</Page>
```

The page simple displays some text to the user and has a button to move to the next screen.  When the page is loaded, the above error shows 4 times in the output window.  Note that the app still works without a problem, I was just curious why am I getting this error and how to prevent it from happening.

Here is the loaded event code:

```js
    function pageLoaded(args) {
    loader.show();
    var page = args.object;

    var lang = appSettings.getString('languageCode', 'en');
    model.set('strings', lang == 'en' ? en : es);

    //get the personal information
    model.set('customer', JSON.parse(global.user));

    //set the greeting
    var greeting = '';
    var hour = (new Date()).getHours();
    if (hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
        greeting = 'Good morning, ' + model.customer.firstName;
    }
    if (hour >= 12 && hour < 17) {
        greeting = 'Good afternoon, ' + model.customer.firstName;
    }
    if (hour >= 17 && hour <= 23) {
        greeting = 'Good evening, ' + model.customer.firstName;
    }
    model.set('greeting', greeting);

    loader.hide();
    page.getViewById('wrapper').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 1000
    });

    model.set('privacy', 'some text');
    model.set('notices', 'some text');

    //set the line height
    var lbl = page.getViewById('text');
    func.labelLineHeight(lbl);

    page.bindingContext = model;

    if (page.ios) {
        var fontSize = 14;
        var fontName = 'HelveticaNeue';
        var hp = page.getViewById('h-privacy');
        hp.ios.font = UIFont.fontWithNameSize(fontName, fontSize);
        hp.marginLeft = -5;
        var hn = page.getViewById('h-notices');
        hn.ios.font = UIFont.fontWithNameSize(fontName, fontSize);
        hn.marginLeft = -5;
    }
    }
```

project.json:

```html
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.company.appname"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "2.14.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.5",
    "nativescript-background-http": "2.4.0",
    "nativescript-email": "1.3.3",
    "nativescript-intl": "0.0.4",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.0.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "2.2.1",
    "nativescript-maskedinput": "0.0.3",
    "nativescript-phone": "1.2.3",
    "nativescript-social-share": "1.3.1",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "1.5.0",
    "nativescript-touchid": "2.1.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.3.0",
    "nativescript-push-notifications": "0.0.19",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "file:nativescript-pdf-view-1.2.0.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Does anyone have a an idea what this is about?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @dpdragnev, please provide some more info about the problem. It will help if you can share some code and project `package.json` file

Comment: I will edit the question with more details.